# Saving prebuffered video from VideoJS player

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video, cross-domain

Hello everyone :) I'm trying to save video from videoJS player as it has option for downloading video, however that link is external and after clicking "download" I'm getting it played in browser. Well actually that's pretty natural as it involves cross domain things, but player itself have it in "memory" I can repeat it etc. but that's player option and download button is just a link, how could I save it locally, I know possibly modifying whole player I would be able to do that, either I don't know if even this way this could be solution as I'm not coder, just doing some technical moderation and saving owners spending's.

```
<script src="//7ds7.github.io/videojs-vjsdownload/dist/videojs-vjsdownload.js"></script>
<script>
    var player = videojs(document.querySelector('.video-js'), {
      plugins: {
        vjsdownload:{
          beforeElement: 'playbackRateMenuButton',
          textControl: 'Download video',
          name: 'downloadButton',
          downloadURL: 'https://optional_downloadURL.mp4' //optional if you need a different download url than the source
        }
      }
    } , function() {
      console.log('Callback video-js initiated');
      this.on('downloadvideo', function(){
      console.log('downloadvideo triggered'); 
    });
  });
</script>
```

Maybe I could use work arounds like telling that this is archive using "source type" ? Well actually I know who did that, at least person tells me that. However I can't provide source as it obfuscated.
Thank you very much with help pointing me right way to solve this problem, at least from technical side, even right direction to move further would be more than enough as everyone just telling it's impossible, but I have played video on my PC :-)

Good luck to everyone!

Comment: Is it possible to show what the link looks like?

Comment: Thanks for reply Viney, to be more clear I made a brief summary http://yt2file.me/demo.html